# How can I turn off the logToTranscript in pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I initially used logTotranscript to check the server activity on the transcript. Now it constantly display on every single transcript I open for other tasks. How can turn it off in the ZnClient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute this:

```
ZnLogEvent stopLoggingToTranscript
```